Using Table until the result equals a number, and returning the number of repetitions
I have a function q, and the exact value of the integral of q from 0 to 2m is nint, where m=1.98355. I do Simpson's rule using the simpRule function, right now its only doing it 30 times i.e. for 1 to 30 strips. I want to see how fast it converges by performing the Simpson's rule, until the result is equal to nint and keeping a count, how do I do that? I guess the count could just be the number of strips where it converges to the exact value (nint), I just don't know how to do that
m=1.98355;
q[x_] := (Cos[4*m*x]^4)/Exp[x]
nint = NIntegrate[q[x], {x, 0, 2*m}]
simpRule[q_, n_?EvenQ, a_, b_] := Block[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
  Sum[h/3*(q[a + (i - 1)*h] + 4*q[a + i*h] + q[a + (i + 1)*h]), {i, 1, n - 1, 2}]]

simpValues = Table[simpRule[q, n, 0, 2*m], {n, 1, 30}]


The programming pattern you are looking for is usually called a While loop. However, note that your condition of being "equal" to nint is not really well-defined when doing numerical calculations. Instead, we usually require a certain numerical accuracy $\epsilon$.
Trying to work upon your code:
m = Rationalize[1.98355];
q[x_] := (Cos[4*m*x]^4)/Exp[x];
nint = Integrate[q[x], {x, 0, 2*m}];

simpRule[q_, n_?EvenQ, a_, b_] := 
 Block[{h = (b - a)/n}, 
  Sum[h/3*(q[a + (i - 1)*h] + 4*q[a + i*h] + q[a + (i + 1)*h]), {i, 1, n - 1, 2}]]

countSteps[ϵ_] := Module[{n = 2}, 
 While[Abs[simpRule[q, n, 0, 2*m] - nint] >= ϵ, n += 2]; n]

countSteps[0.001]
(* 8 *)
countSteps[0.0001]
(* 66 *)
countSteps[0.00001]
(* 106 *)

The greater the accuracy you want, the more steps you need.
ListLogLogPlot[
 Table[{10^-logϵ, count[10^-logϵ]}, {logϵ, 
   2, 10, 0.5}], AxesLabel -> {"ϵ", "Steps required"}]


